# Using ifstream as fscanf

Tags: c++, c, scanf, ifstream

Assume that I have an input as follows:

```
N (X_1,Y_1) (X_2,Y_2) .... (X_N, Y_N)
```

where N, X_i and Y_i are integers.

An example:

```
2 (55,1) (521,7)
```

To read this, I can do something like this(assume all variables are defined, etc.):

```
fscanf(fin,"%d ",&N);
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
   fscanf(fin,"(%d,%d) ", &X[i], &Y[i]);
```

The question is, how can I do this easily using ifstream. I can get string's, and then I can get rid of nondigits and using stringstream I can get two numbers but this seems a bit cumbersome. Is there an easier, more elegant way?

Thanks

Comment: why not just use scanf as you're already doing? or are you asking because you want to learn?

Comment: I'm asking just because I want to learn =)

Comment: The last time I suggested using C-style IO in a C++ program all the C++ elites on SO all had a go at me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
int n, x, y;
char c;
if (is >> n)
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        if (is >> c && c == '(' &&
            is >> x &&
            is >> c && c == ',' &&
            is >> y &&
            is >> c && c == ')')
        {
            X[i] = x;
            Y[i] = y;
        }
        else
            throw std::runtime_error("invalid inputs");
```

You can simplify the all-important inner `if` condition above to...

```
is >> chlit('(') >> x >> chlit(',') >> y >> chlit(')')
```

...with a simple support type for consuming a specific character:

```
struct chlit
{
    chlit(char c) : c_(c) { }
    char c_;
};

inline std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, chlit x)
{
    char c;
    if (is >> c && c != x.c_)
        is.setstate(std::iostream::failbit);
    return is;
}
```

See a complete program illustrating this [on ideone here](http://ideone.com/wqosyc).

An old post of mine did something similar for consuming specific strings.  (The above `chlit` could be a template, but `chlit<','>()` is ugly to read and write - I'd rather trust the compiler).

Comment: From 3 lines to 15 . . . I really like C++ but the iostreams can be hard to work with sometimes.

Comment: well at least it will not cause a memory overwrite if there is something unexpected in the input.

Comment: @Anders: fscanf stops scanning on unexpected input, and returns the number of items successfully scanned.

Comment: @dreamlax: if you want to make it more concise, you can get some milage out of `if (is >> c1 >> X[i] >> c2 >> Y[i] >> c3 && c1 == '(' && c2 == ',' && c3 == ')')`

Comment: @Anders: input is assumed to be perfect for this question

Comment: Will this actually work thuogh, won't the first `is >> c` result in a space character? (I think only leading ws is consumed when reading integers)

Comment: @dreamlax: re memory overwrites, the problem is that a lot of beginners don't protect against overwriting string buffers... you can use formats like "%.20s" or "%.*s" but a lot of beginners people don't.  Further, they often try to use `%s` where `%[...]` is needed.

Comment: @roe: good thing to be wary of, but no - streaming to a `char` will also skip whitespace unless you change the stream state beforehand.

Comment: @Tony: I'm with you on reading strings using `fscanf`, and also the enconcisening is good too. I think it's a good answer (+1'd).

Answer (score 3):

```
cin >> N;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    cin.ignore(100,'(');
    cin >> X[i];
    cin.ignore(100,',');
    cin >> Y[i];
    cin.ignore(100,')');
}
```

It can handle whitespaces also, as it can read input like:

```
2  (  1  ,  3  )    (  5  ,  6  )
```

Demonstration at ideone: http://www.ideone.com/hO0xG